# How to show Push Notification from server side in my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications, server-push

I am trying to implement push notification in my iPhone application and some short I am successful but I am getting this error:

> Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 'no valid' aps- environment' entitlement string found for application UserInfor=0x170140 {NSLOcalizedDescription=no valid 'aps- environment' entitlement string found for application}`

Please help me how can I connect to my web-service and how to resolve this error.

Please help me how can I resolve this error? Thank you. Is there any video just share with me. Thank ja.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a certificate for this, read this tutorial http://www.xcode-tutorials.com/programming-apple-push-notification-services-apns/

Also, push will not work in the simulator